# How to make progress dialog for Bash in XFCE?

Tags: bash, xfce, window

Previously, in KDE, this was simple -- I called KDialog with number of steps, I got DCOP handle in return, then I called dcop with that reference and step, and progress dialog got updated.

However, now DCOP is obsolete, and since I moved from KDE 3.5.10 to XFCE, I thought it would be a good idea that instead converting my script from KDialog+DCOP to KDialog+DBUS I migrate to XFCE progress dialog.

**So how do you build progress dialog for Bash purposes in XFCE?** Bash purpose = I perform some computation in Bash, but the progress is shown in GUI way, as nice dialog on the desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *dialog* utility. It can works both [inside and outside](http://cstropz.net/2011/11/21/dialogs-xfce4-whiptail-zenity/) a terminal.

To get it on the X server, you may use its [xdialog](http://xdialog.free.fr/) or [gdialog/zenity](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_gdialog.htm) variant. Take note that zenity is recommendend for XFCE, since its use GTK+.
In fact, I think Kdialog is a KDE variant of Xdialog.

Here is a simple Zenity script, running on X server with a yes/no box :

```
DIALOG=zenity
$DIALOG --title " My first dialog" --clear \
--yesno "Hi, this is my first dialog" 10 30
```

Here's a simple [tutorial](http://unstableme.blogspot.fr/2009/12/linux-dialog-utility-short-tutorial.html) with various example about the different dialog available. And there's also [a nice tutorial](http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/265/a-complete-zenity-dialog-examples-2/) about zenity.

About your graphical progress dialog, there's [one dedicated for this purpose](http://library.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/zenity-progress-options.html.en). Here's the sample script of the documentation :

```
#!/bin/sh
(
echo "10" ; sleep 1
echo "# Updating mail logs" ; sleep 1
echo "20" ; sleep 1
echo "# Resetting cron jobs" ; sleep 1
echo "50" ; sleep 1
echo "This line will just be ignored" ; sleep 1
echo "75" ; sleep 1
echo "# Rebooting system" ; sleep 1
echo "100" ; sleep 1
) |
zenity --progress \
  --title="Update System Logs" \
  --text="Scanning mail logs..." \
  --percentage=0

if [ "$?" = -1 ] ; then
        zenity --error \
          --text="Update canceled."
fi
```

Comment: If anyone is wondering how to mimic KDialog further and use zenity as monitor in the background here is how I did it -- http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38807/how-to-pass-data-outside-process-for-zenity-progress/38846#38846