# Inform me when extraction of RAR archive (with unar via Thunar custom action) is finished

Tags: thunar, rar, progress-information

I created a custom action in Thunar for extracting RAR archives with [unar](https://unarchiver.c3.cx/commandline):

```
unar %N
```

It works, but it doesn’t inform me when it’s done.

Is it possible to show some kind of indicator (e.g., a progress bar) while it’s extracting? Or a notification as soon as it’s finished?

Comment: xfce-terminal -e unrar %N

Comment: @sourcejedi: Thanks. I guess I have to use `xfce4-terminal` (instead of `xfce-terminal`), and it’s `unar` (instead of `unrar`), but I doesn’t seem to work: nothing happens. When I omit the `%N` (so I have: `xfce4-terminal -e unar`), the terminal window at least gets opened, but automatically closed immediately after.

Comment: Sorry!  Testing fail.  It works with xterm, but not gnome-terminal.  `gnome-terminal -e "sleep 1"` works, and fortunately `gnome-terminal -e "sleep 1;command-injected-by-evil-filename"` shows an error.  I would recommend running these tests xfce4-terminal before using it :).

Comment: Except it won't work for files with spaces in them, dammit.  It might almost be safe with a command like `unar -- %N`, but I still hate it.

Comment: How do you feel about installing the original xterm :). Don't squint, it's bad for your eyes.

Comment: @sourcejedi: I already had xterm installed (Debian 8 + Xfce seems to install it by default). Using `xterm -e unar %N` seems to work fine for my test file. Do you want to create an answer?

Comment: As an alternative, you could use zenity for a more GUI type approach. Good starting point would be [How to pass data outside process for zenity progress?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38807/how-to-pass-data-outside-process-for-zenity-progress) and [How to make progress dialog for Bash in XFCE?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34391/how-to-make-progress-dialog-for-bash-in-xfce).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always run the command in a terminal.

Your notification is when the terminal closes itself :).  It will also show whatever progress / activity indicator is provided by the unar command.

1. `gnome-terminal -x unar -- %N`

   I have not tested whether `xfce4-terminal` accepts the `-x` option.
2. `xterm -e unar -- %N`

   `uxrvt` should also accept the `-e` option.

   Apologies in advance for any eyestrain due to running xterm with its default font size.

gnome-terminal also has a -e option. With gnome-terminal, the option takes a single command argument, and splits in based on spaces.  E.g. `gnome-terminal -e "sleep 1"`.  We can't use this because filenames could also contain spaces.  With xterm, `-e` can actually behave either way, depending on how many arguments you pass.  So the behaviour of gnome-terminal is less magic and probably nicer, provided you don't mind that `gnome-terminal --help` fails to document either option.

Comment: Why do you keep whining about default `xterm` fonts?  Just set the defaults once and for all in your `~/.Xresources`, and then all `xterm`s will use them, happily ever after.

Comment: @SatoKatsura I whine because I should have to configure at most *one* terminal emulator (and it should have sensible defaults anyway). My DE's terminal emulator failed to document that it supported the necessary option in its `--help`. Whereas I was able to find documentation on xterm. So at this point I had no evidence that gnome-terminal supported this use case. The whine is that there should have been no reason for me to install and run an extra app for this purpose; the font size is a concrete example of why it was a bad idea. I have not tested the terminal emulator for OP's DE either.

Comment: Well, consistency is expensive.  You can't really expect consistency from projects whose philosophical model is a bazaar.  CDE, NeXT, and OpenWindows were consistent.  Gnome and KDE, not so much. _shrug_

Comment: Hmm? _My DE's terminal emulator failed to document that it supported the necessary option... there should have been no reason for me to install and run [xterm]_. gnome-terminal is consistent with gnome. Fedora Workstation did not install xterm for me. I don't think any of the ancient terminal emulators (with ancient defaults) even show up in gnome-software. Also google web search only knew to tell me about xterm. I've seen SE answers fix that sort of thing before.

Comment: _I whine because I should have to configure at most one terminal emulator (and it should have sensible defaults anyway)._ - This is the kind of consistency I'm talking about.